# Python: Popen().stdout.peek() hangs

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I'm trying to integrate a REPL-like command line program into a Python project.  The command line program takes an input string and returns an output string, and it works fine when run on its own.  The problem is that when I try to use `Popen().stdout.peek()` or `.read()` on it, it hangs and doesn't produce output.

```
>>> p = Popen('Test.exe', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
>>> p.stdin.write(bytes('message\n', 'utf-8'))
8
>>> p.stdin.flush()
>>> p.stdout.peek()  # Hangs
```

Interestingly this does work if the command line program is written in Python too, but when using the one I actually want to use it hangs.  Both programs behave as expected when run manually in the command line.  I also can't use `p.communicate('message')` because the process is stateful and I need to execute multiple commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the most likely scenario is that you have to close the stdin PIPE, before the subprocess starts executing and printing something. Most likely scenario is that the subprocess is still wainting for input.

You might want to try debug as such, close the stdin and see if that works:

```
p.stdin.close()
p.stdout.read()
```

If that works see what the subprocess expects as an END of command. E.g. it might be that it expects `\r\n` insted of `\n`. Without knowing how the underlying process works, it's difficult to say what's going wrong here.

Comment: Closing `stdin` prevents `peek()` from blocking and prints out the expected result with `\r\n` appended (regardless of whether it was appended to the input or not).  If I append that to the input, however, `peek()` still hangs unless `stdin` is closed manually.

Comment: If the program simply uses the C runtime's default standard I/O settings, the isssue is more likely that stdout is fully buffered when it's not a tty, such as a pipe or disk file. Closing stdin signals the application to exit, at which time it flushes the stdout buffer to the pipe. Check whether the application has a command-line option that forces stdout to be line-buffered or unbuffered.

Comment: This worked, thanks.  The subprocess is written in Haskell and needed `hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering` and `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering` added to the main function before entering the loop.